# Fill UITableViewCell with UITextView (Static Cells)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextview

If I have a static uitableviewcell with a textview inside it, how am I able to set the height of the uitableviewcell to fit all of the textview content on it?

Comment: Make the `UITableViewCell`'s height equal to `UITextView`s height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

You can use an If-else condition to make it what ever height you want as long as you return a number(CGFloat)